# Is it possible for quasiparticles to form charge density wave of quasiparticles?

Tags: condensed-matter, interactions, quasiparticles

What if the quasiparticle has fractional charge?

-----UPDATE------

For example, 1d kink has e/2 charge, if view kink like electrons in 1d (we know there is 1d charge density wave of electrons), is there CDW of kinks?

Comment: Which quasiparticle? An "electron quasiparticle"? (In which case the short answer is no, it doesn't have fractional charge)

Comment: It isn't necessary to be electron quasiparticles, it is just some kind of quasiparticles which has charge.